# I can't get Vulkan vkCmdBindVertexBuffers2 to work and I don't know why

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to bind my vertex buffers using this API:

https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdBindVertexBuffers2.html

which is almost identical of the standard API counterpart, except that allows to set dynamic strides.

https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCmdBindVertexBuffers.html

However, in my test program it keeps crashing and the validation layers shows me nothing either :( I can't spot the bug. Here is what I have tried:

My vertex array:

```
const std::vector<Vertex> vertices =
{
    {{0.0f, 0.0f},  {0.21f, 0.41f, 0.61f}},
    {{0.0f, 1.0f},  {0.21f, 0.41f, 0.61f}},
    {{1.0f, 0.0f},  {0.21f, 0.41f, 0.61f}},
    {{1.0f, 1.0f},  {0.21f, 0.41f, 0.61f}},
};
```

my vertices attribs and desc

```
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec2 pos;
    glm::vec3 color;

    static VkVertexInputBindingDescription getBindingDescription() {
        VkVertexInputBindingDescription bindingDescription{};
        bindingDescription.binding = 0;
        bindingDescription.stride = sizeof(Vertex);
        bindingDescription.inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX;
        return bindingDescription;
    }

    static std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 2> getAttributeDescriptions() {
        std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 2> attributeDescriptions{};
        attributeDescriptions[0].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].location = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[0].offset = offsetof(Vertex, pos);
        attributeDescriptions[1].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[1].location = 1;
        attributeDescriptions[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[1].offset = offsetof(Vertex, color);
        return attributeDescriptions;
    }
};
```

The pipeline gets created without any errors Here is what I have when binding the vertex buffer.

```
            VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = {vertexBuffer};
            VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};

            // 5 floats x 4 vertices
            VkDeviceSize    sizes[] = {sizeof(float) * 5 * 4};
            VkDeviceSize    strides[] = { sizeof(Vertex) };

#if 0
            // this works
            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
#else
            // this crashes :(
            vkCmdBindVertexBuffers2(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets, sizes, strides);
#endif

            vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(vertices.size()), 1, 0, 0);
```

To make matter worse, if I use the standard vkCmdBindVertexBuffers without the extra parameters, it works fine. It it just drawing a quad with with tri strip.

I am using vulkan API

```
Vulkan Version:1.3.236
```

According to the docs, I don't need to enable extensions. But just in case I also tried to enable the extension via the dynamic states as follows:

```
const std::vector<const char*> deviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_EXTENDED_DYNAMIC_STATE_2_EXTENSION_NAME,
};

...

        std::vector<VkDynamicState> dynamicStates = {
            VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
            VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR,
            VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VERTEX_INPUT_BINDING_STRIDE_EXT,
            VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VERTEX_INPUT_BINDING_STRIDE,
        };
        VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState{};
        dynamicState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DYNAMIC_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
        dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(dynamicStates.size());
        dynamicState.pDynamicStates = dynamicStates.data();
```

But made no difference. The same exact crash :(

Here is the crash, notice that all pointers and handles are valid. It happens right inside the call to "vkCmdBindVertexBuffers2"

[image]

Anyone can help me spotting the bug? I really can't see it.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers2` is probably null. Is that function getting imported with `vkGetDeviceProcAddr`?

Comment: no, it was just version requirement. See below, but thx for reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from my discussions on Discord:

https://discord.com/channels/427551838099996672/427951557045387276/1170966659171876934

Basically, I missed specifying API 1.3.x which is required for this extension. Weird how the validation layers did not report anything.

```
// this is the issue, V 1.0.0 does not support the API
//appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

// the quick fix
appInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 3, 0);
```

Yet, the proper fix requires a check of VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.apiVersion to see if my graphics card supports it.

Big thanks to Alex on discord to showed me the issue.